# Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Hello guys i'm getting this message when i'm trying to delete an entry in my DB.
I have tried JSON.parse on the req.body,switched the routes in my routes file yet nothing seems to work.

this is my controller :

```
async function removeToy(req, res) {
  try {
    const { toyId } = req.params
    const removedId = await toyService.remove(toyId)
    res.send(removedId)
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error('Failed to remove toy', err)
    res.status(500).send({ err: 'Failed to remove toy' })
  }
}
```

this is the service :

```
async function remove(toyId) {

  try {
      const collection = await dbService.getCollection('toy')
      await collection.deleteOne({ '_id': ObjectId(toyId)})
      return toyId
  } catch (err) {
      logger.error(`cannot remove toy ${toyId}`, err)
      throw err
  }
}
```

also added a picture of how the DB looks like:
[image]

and the picture of the entire error :
[image]

appreciating any kind of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your database you have an object whose _id is of type `string`.

In your query, you're casting (presumably) a `string` to an `ObjectID`, which is an object. Not only is the argument you're passing to `ObjectId()` not something that it supports (as the error indicates, see below), *even if it would be valid*, the query would result in 0 hits: after all `"TZ23c" !== ObjectId("TZ23c")`.

Simply change `.deleteOne({_id: ObjectId(toyId)})` to `.deleteOne({_id: toyId})`.

`ObjectId()` either takes no argument (it will return a new value) or it takes exactly 12 bytes (24 hexadecimal characters), for example: `ObjectId("61e16f21f82a9db6a2094e78")`.

An ObjectId's string representation (`ObjectId().toString()`) is not an arbitrary string of characters: it's a timestamp, some values that identify which server generated it and some random values to prevent collisions. Not every string is a valid ObjectId.

Answer (score 0):

As the message suggest your toyId passed to the function is with wrong lenght , it must be 12 bytes long , example:

```
  mongos> ObjectId("x448c")
  2022-01-14T13:43:51.427+0100 E QUERY    [js] Error: invalid object id: length 
  :
  @(shell):1:1
  mongos>
```

The correct is:

```
  mongos> ObjectId("61e16facafe3aa6023c221bb")
  ObjectId("61e16facafe3aa6023c221bb")
```